# Conditional email receipt subject line

Tags: contribution-page, receipts

I am using a contribution page to sell an item. I would like to enable the receipt section so that people get an email confirmation of their purchase.

My problem is that our receipt (on-line) template uses the subject line "Thank you for your donation - tax receipt for [contribution page title]"

Obviously this is not a donation and no tax receipt will be issued (the non-deductible amount equals the purchase price).

I don't know enough to edit the current code to achieve this, hoping someone can help.

I do need to keep the "if pay later" then "invoice" part as well.

`{if $is_pay_later}{ts}Invoice{/ts}{else}{ts}Thank you for your Donation,  Tax Receipt for{/ts}{/if} - {$title} - {contact.display_name}`

Comment: If you are using a different Financial Type for your 'purchases' then yes i think you should be able to add in some more if/else and keep the PayLater if/else

Comment: Yes I am using a different financial type - do you know the code for "if financial type ="?

Answer (score 0):

Checked on one of our sites and what I am seeing is that for Financial Type 6 we are using

> {if $ft_id == 6}

Comment: I don't think $ft_id is something from core and I don't see it in the code. Is that something custom, possibly assigned to the template from php or maybe a few lines up in your template you have `{crmAPI var='ft_id' ...}` where you look it up based on the contribution id? In theory as of 5.43-ish you can use `{contribution.financial_type_id}` but it may not be available in all message templates. If using within a smarty `if` you might need to surround it with single quotes, but might not be necessary in this specific case, e.g. `{if '{contribution.financial_type_id}' == 4}`

Comment: hmm. i see some customisation with *_civicrm_alterMailParams() and "if ($contribution['financial_type_id'] == 6) {
  $params['tplParams']['logoURL'] ="

Comment: hopefully your comment has suggestions they can use and then perhaps you should change it to an Answer and I will bury mine

Comment: I decided just to change the wording of the subject to "contribution" instead of "donation", that way it works for donations and purchases both!

Comment: Love those types of solutions.